# Bluetooth pairing from command line in android JB 4.1.1

Tags: android, command-line, bluetooth, bluez, android-bluetooth

In my reference board, i am using Android Jelly Bean 4.1.1. I want to use bluetooth from command line. I know commands for enable/disable bluetooth, scanning the devices etc. ,But I don't know how to pair with the scanned device from command line. Android Jelly Bean 4.1.1 is using Bluez stack for bluetooth. can anyone help me so I can pair my board with other bluetooth device from command line. Thanks.

Comment: This will help u for connecting from command prompt: http://zitzlinux.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/connecting-bluetooth-devices-from-command-line/

Comment: How will this help on Android?

Answer (score 0):

This worked like a charm for me, of-course it requires super-user privileges :)

`# hcitool cc <target-bdaddr>; hcitool auth <target-bdaddr>`

[Courtesy](http://pfalcon-oe.blogspot.com/2011/12/pairing-bluetooth-devices-from-command.html)